# Is there a way to determine where on Scrollbar the user clicked/dragged?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, scrollbar

I have a winforms VB.NET app with a textbox which contains a list of memory addresses and a vertical scrollbar. I want to be able to scroll the textbox based on where the user clicked or dragged in the scrollbar. For example:

If the user clicked in the up/down arrow part of the scrollbar then I want the scrollbar value to change by 1 (the smallchange value).

If the 'channel' (the part between the up/down arrow and the thumb) is clicked then I want to scroll by some calculated amount.

If the thumb is dragged, I just want to use the value of the scrollbar. (The largechange value)

No doubt I'm missing something obvious here!

Comment: The LargeChange value is what happens when the user clicks between the scroll arrow and the thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out how the user clicked the ScrollBar, use the Scroll event and look at the Type property of the ScrollEventArgs:

```
Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll
    If e.Type = ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement Then
        'User clicked the right (or bottom) scroll arrow
    End If

    If e.Type = ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement Then
        'User clicked the left (or top) scroll arrow
    End If

    If e.Type = ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement Then
        'User clicked the area between the right (or bottom) scroll arrow and the thumb
    End If

    If e.Type = ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement Then
        'User clicked the area between the left (or top) scroll arrow and the thumb
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that those scroll types could also indicate if the user pressed a keyboard key to scroll.  For example, the up (or left) arrow key would have a type of SmallDecrement.

Answer (score 0):

As I Know that VScrollBar is only have `SmallChange` and `LargeChange` properties for value setting ..

This is for sample only ..

```
VScrollBar1.Minimum = 0
VScrollBar1.Maximum = 100
VScrollBar1.SmallChange = 1
VScrollBar1.LargeChange = SetValue()


Function SetValue() as Integer '----> result must be < VScrollBar1.Max

    'Return Integer value

End Function
```